# Remove back to back duplicates of a list on python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I want to delete the back to back duplicates of a list.

```
myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "D"]
```

I want to get this list:

```
A, B, C, D, A, B, C, B, D
```

I tried converting it into a set then back to a list but I keep deleting all duplicates and not just

```
list2 = list(set(myList))        
list2.sort(key=list1.index)    
print list2


> [ A, B, C, D]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "D"]
>>> [x[0] for x in groupby(l)]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way, but a linear scan and keeping track of the previous element can work.

```
myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "D"]

output = []
prev = None
for x in myList:
  if prev != x:
    output.append(x)
  prev = x
```

```
>>> print(output) 
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D']
```

My simple tests say this also handles more than two back-to-back elements

Answer (score 0):

A simple (if inelegant) solution would be to append valid elements to a new list:

```
mylist = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "D"]
newlist = []
prevchar = ''

for char in mylist:

    if char != prevchar:
        newlist.append(char)

    prevchar = char
```

Comment: You don't need `else: continue`. Works just fine without it :)

Comment: @TemporalWolf True! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can, here is a function which uses a generator and a list comprehension:

```
# Generator which returns whether the last character is the same
# as the one you just sent it
def is_diff():
    last = char = None
    while True:
        diff = last != char
        last = char
        char = yield diff

def de_dupe(list):
    gen_diff = is_diff()
    gen_diff.send(None)  # These steps are required to initiate the generator
    return [char for char in list if gen_diff.send(char)]
```

Used as:

```
de_dupe(my_list)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D']
```